# Is there a function for get n elements from firebase realtime database?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

My code consists of 3 swift files for create a dynamic prototype `UITableViewController`.

1) Rent_house_Controller.swift

2) Rent_house_Cell.swift

3) Rent_house_Detail.swift

First of all I connected `UITableViewCell`'s objects to the dedicated swift file:

```
@IBOutlet weak var rentImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var rentLabel: UILabel!
```

Then I defined my `UITableViewController`:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class Case_in_affitto: UITableViewController,
UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

var rentImages = [String]()
var rentNames = [String]()
var webAddresses = [String]()

var searching = false
var matches = [Int]()
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    initialize()
}

func initialize() {
    rentNames = ["Red Street",
                       "Green Street",
                       "Blue steet",
                       "Yellow Street",
                       "Colour Square"]

    webAddresses = ["https://website.com/rents/Red-Street",
                    "https://website.com/rents/Green-Street",
                    "https://website.com/rents/Blue-Street",
                    "https://website.com/rents/Yellow-Street",
                    "https://website.com/rents/Colour-Square"]

    rentImages = ["Red-Street.jpg",
                        "Green-Street.jpg",
                        "Blue-Street.jpg",
                        "Yellow-Street.jpg",
                        "Colour-Square.jpg"]

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Cerca immobile"
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    definesPresentationContext = true
    let attributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
    ]
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).title = "Annulla"
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: Search Controller
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text,
        !searchText.isEmpty {
        matches.removeAll()

        for index in 0..<rentNames.count {
            if rentNames[index].lowercased().contains(
                searchText.lowercased()) {
                matches.append(index)
            }
        }
        searching = true
    } else {
        searching = false
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searching = false
    tableView.reloadData()
}



// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return searching ? matches.count : rentNames.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"rentTableCell", for: indexPath) as! Case_in_Affitto_Cell

    let row = indexPath.row
    cell.rentLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.headline)
    cell.rentLabel.text = searching ? rentNames[matches[row]] : rentNames[row]
    let imageName = searching ? rentImages[matches[row]] : rentImages[row]

    cell.rentImage.image = UIImage(named: imageName)

    return cell
}



override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowrentDetails" {

        let detailViewController = segue.destination
            as! Case_in_Affitto_Detail

        let myIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let row = myIndexPath.row
        detailViewController.webSite =
            searching ? webAddresses[matches[row]] : webAddresses[row]
    }
}

//Set cells height
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0,1,2,3,4:
        return 100
    default:
        return 40
    }
}


}
```

In this case, I have a classical `UITableViewController` which displays the values that I implemented in the project, but I need something different.

I want to make n cells given by the amount of nodes that I have in database.

For example:

```
{
"Sales":"",
"Rents":[
{
"Address":"Green_Street",
"Rooms":"2",
"Price":"70000"
},
{
"Address":"Red_Street",
"Rooms":"2",
"Price":"70000"
},
{
"Address":"Blue_Street",
"vani":"2",
"Price":"70000"
},
{
"Address":"Yellow_Street",
"Rooms":"2",
"Price":"70000"
},
{
"Address":"Colour_Square",
"Rooms":"4",
"Price":"140000"
}
]
}
```

In other words, the first problem is that one day, the number of houses will increase or decrease so, I need to make a functions witch automatically populates the table by the number of nodes of my database.?

---

**Edit:**

I made something. 
I created a new `UIViewController` which calls data from database and then I want to pass all this data by `UserDefaults.standard`

The Image is provided by URL retrieved by database, so I added also key "imageURL".

Loading.swift:

```
if codesArray.contains("0") {
                    let userRef = rootRef.child("Rents").child("0")

                        userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                            let userDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]

                            let rentAddress = userDict["Address"] as! String
                            self.address = rentAddress

                            let rentnumberOfRooms = userDict["numberOfRooms"] as! String
                            self.numberOfRooms = rentnumberOfRooms

                            let rentPrice = userDict["Price"] as! String
                            self.price = rentPrice

                            let rentimageURL = userDict["imageURL"] as! String
                            self.imageURL = rentimageURL
                            //save data on UserDefaults
                            self.savedata()
                            //loading finished
                            self.loading.stopAnimating()
                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loadingfinish", sender: self)
                        })
                } else {
                    self.loading.stopAnimating()
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Errore", message: "Caricamento annunci non riuscito", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
```

How can I change this condition to load every subnest of node "Rent"?

(Remember that we don't know how much childs have Rents)

---

**Edit 2:**

I'm doing my best to find this solution.
I thought to use `nextObject` parameter on a while cicle to check if there are others objects in the database to store in the `var address = [String]()`

```
//setting firebase database
                        while (snapshotChildren.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot) != nil {

                            let string_child = snapshotChildren.nextObject() as? String

                            let userRef = rootRef.child("Rents").child(string_child!)

                                userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                                    let userDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]

                                    self.address.append(userRef.value(forKey: "Address") as! String)

                                    let rentnumberOfRooms = userDict["numberOfRooms"] as! NSMutableArray
                                    self.numberOfRooms = rentnumberOfRooms

                                    let rentPrice = userDict["Price"] as! NSMutableArray
                                    self.price = rentPrice

                                    let rentimageURL = userDict["imageURL"] as! NSMutableArray
                                    self.imageURL = rentimageURL
                                    //avvio salvataggio dati del volontario
                                    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
                                        let vc = segue.destination as! Case_in_affitto

                                        var i = 0
                                        while i==5 {
                                            //this will pass the value on the address array in the Case_in_affitto.swift file
                                            vc.address.append(self.address[i])
                                            i += 1
                                        }

                                    }
                                })
                        }
                        //loading complete
                        self.loading.stopAnimating()
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loadingfinish", sender: self)
```

Unfortunately this is not correct

Answer (score 1):

*Il codice è abbastanza orribile*  (The code is quite horrible)

Don't use multiple arrays as data source. You'll already get in trouble in the search function.

Use a custom struct with all parameters you need, the image is represented by its name in the bundle

```
struct Rent {
    let address : String
    let numberOfRooms : Int
    let price : String
    let image : String
}
```

The initializer

```
init(address : String, numberOfRooms : Int, price : String, image : String)
```

is included for free.

The declare **one** data source array and populate it from the database

```
var rents = [Rent]()
```

Declare `matches` with the same type

```
var matches = [Rent]()
```

and use this optimized code to filter the objects, the `diacriticInsensitive` is quite useful for Italian text.

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text,
        !searchText.isEmpty {
        matches = rents.filter{ $0.name.range(of: searchText, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]) != nil }
        searching = true
    } else {
        matches.removeAll()
        searching = false
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

The corresponding table view delegate methods are

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return searching ? matches.count : rents.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"rentTableCell", for: indexPath) as! Case_in_Affitto_Cell
    let object = searching ? matches[indexPath.row] : rents[indexPath.row]

    cell.rentLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.headline)
    cell.rentLabel.text = object.name
    cell.rentImage.image = UIImage(named: object.image)

    return cell
}
```

If the images are not supposed to be located in the bundle, save the URLs in the database and the physical images in the `Documents` folder.
In this case declare

```
let imageURL : URL
```

in the struct and assign the image

```
cell.rentImage.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: object.imageURL.path)
```

Comment: thank you, very kind! But debbugger says 'Initializers may only be declared within a type'

Comment: I understood that I had to put all these codes in the Controller.
Here all the errors:

in function initialize: init(address : String...) line: Initializers may only be declared within a type

class Case_in_affitto line: Type 'Case_in_affitto' does not conform to protocol 'UISearchResultsUpdating'
Class 'Case_in_affitto' has no initializers

matches = rents.filter line: Value of type 'Rent' has no member 'name'

cell.rentLabel.text = obkect.name line: Value of type 'Rent' has no member 'name'

Comment: cell.rentImage.image = UIImage line: Value of type 'Rent' has no member 'imageURL'

in function prepare on searching ? webAddresses[matches[row]] : webAddresses[row] line: Cannot subscript a value of type '[String]' with an index of type 'Rent'

Comment: Declare the struct outside of the class. `var rents...` replaces the three string arrays. In `initialize` delete the initializer line and populate `rents` with `rents = [Rent(name: "Red Street", numberOfRooms: 2, price: "70000", image:  "Red-Street.jpg"), Rent(name: "Blue Street", ....),  Rent(name: "Green Street", ....)]`. `imageURL` is an alternative if the images are not located in the application bundle.

Comment: yes, it works now. But Firebase is still not configured. In this way The cells value are still retrieved by swift file.

In the past I used observer for a known number of rows, but this time we don't know how much data are in database.